# Socket wont join room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

im trying to join a room by default as soon as the client connects. The code runs without errors but doesnt actually put the user in the room i wanted. Here is my code:

```
Server.prototype.startSockets = function() {

this.socket = io.listen(this.server);

this.socket.of('game').on('connection', function(user) {

    user.id = this.userId;
    this.userId++;

    user.join('chat');      
    console.log(user.rooms);

    this.socket.of('game').to('chat').emit('loginError', 'only for test chat.');

    consoleLog('SERVER', '(' + user.id + ' | Guest) has connected');
```

I know for a fact the user is joining, it assigns the connection a user Id and prints to the console that they have connected.

When i log user.rooms, it prints out an empty object {}

Just to clarify consoleLog is a function to put a time stamp and is not a spelling mistake causing an error or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2914

socket.join is an asynchronous call. You'll have to use the callback function to log the rooms.

`user.join('chat', function() {console.log(user.rooms)});`